# Network packet capture in Java without libpcap

Tags: java, networking, packet, libpcap

I was wondering if there are any libraries useful for network packet capture and analysis that do not build off of libpcap? I'm trying to develop a platform-independent application. Thanks

Comment: If you want to develop a platform-independent application for network packet capture, you will either have to use libpcap (or something that builds on top of it) or will have to duplicate what libpcap does, as the way packet capture is done is *very* platform-dependent - libpcap hides the platform dependencies.  I would *strongly* suggest that using libpcap, rather than trying to duplicate what it does, is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This still uses libpcap but does so with JNI, so its still somewhat portable.  Your processing code will be completely portable but is reliant on the JNI calls to interface with the actual network adapter/packets.

http://jnetpcap.com/download